# RHEL6 and RHEl7 in a cluster, or some forests on ext4 and some on xfs?

Tags: marklogic, rhel, marklogic-8, rhel7

I have a large cluster of ML8 servers running on RHEL6 with data on EXT4 filesystems.  We want to migrate to RHEL7 with the data on XFS filesystems.

I want to move the cluster with minimum downtime.  I have been told that I cannot have a cluster of mixed RHEL6 and RHEL7 servers, so I cannot just add RHEL7 servers to the cluster a few at a time and retire an equal number of RHEL6 servers.

First Question:  Can anyone confirm that I cannot have RHEL6 and RHEL7 servers in the same cluster?

So let's say I just spin up RHEL7 servers, and attach the old data disks (EXT4) to the new servers.  Now I want to get that data onto new data disks (XFS) -- add new XFS forests and retire old EXT4 forests.

Second Question: In a cluster, can I have some forests on EXT4 filesystems and some forests on XFS filesystems?

Answer (score 1):

"Cannot have" is an interesting way to ask the question.

*Will the software stop you?*  No.

*Will it work?*  Probably.

*Has anyone in the history of mankind ever tried it?*  I think I saw a customer doing it accidentally once.

*Has MarkLogic QA ever run its test battery against this configuration?*  Bet not.

*Is it an officially supported configuration?*  No.

*Would I do it?*  No.  I like to stick to what's officially tested and supported.

As for mixing filesystems, that's lower risk because each box manages its own filesystem in isolation from the rest.  Nodes communicate directly with each other, filesystems don't.

The docs do say that while XFS is supported and even recommended with MarkLogic 9, it's not listed as officially supported with MarkLogic 8.